# How do I create a custom Diesel query using SQL functions with user-provided inputs?

Tags: sql, rust, rust-diesel

I want to perform a query that uses custom SQL functions of PostGIS bundles. For instance, I can run the subsequent query with psql:

```sql
SELECT * FROM places 
WHERE earth_box(ll_to_earth(40.6333125,-8.659492), 20)
@> ll_to_earth(places.lat, places.lng);
```

`ll_to_earth` and `earth_box` are PostGIS functions. How can I make this query with Diesel with those values of `lat` and `lng` as input?

I browsed the documentation but I can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 8):

This was the solution I ended up with:

```
pub fn get_near(lat: f32, lng: f32, conn: &PgConnection) -> Vec<Places> {
    diesel::sql_query("SELECT * FROM places WHERE earth_box(ll_to_earth($1,$2), 20) @> ll_to_earth(places.lat, places.lng)")
        .bind::<diesel::sql_types::Float, _>(lat)
        .bind::<diesel::sql_types::Float, _>(lng)
        .load(conn)
        .expect("An error has occured")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Searching the Diesel documentation for `function`](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.3.3/diesel/?search=function) leads directly to the [`sql_function`](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.3.3/diesel/macro.sql_function.html) macro:

> Diesel only provides support for a very small number of SQL functions. This macro enables you to add additional functions from the SQL standard, as well as any custom functions your application might have.